# How do I declare a countably infinite list of variables as being integers?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I want to do this,

```
Solve[ { n1 + n2 + n3 + .... = 10, n1 + 2 n2 + 3 n3 + .... = 100}, 
{n1,n2,n3,....}, Assumptions -> {n1,n2,n3,.... are Integers >=0} ]
```

Note that here .... means "ad infinitum" . Can someone write a genuine Mathematica code that solves this system?

Comment: Are you asking if Mathematica can calculate values for $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, ... , $n_{\infty - 3}$, $n_{\infty - 2}$, $n_{\infty - 1}$, $n_{\infty}$? How exactly would you display the solutions or store them in memory?

Comment: Have you seen `FrobeniusSolve[]`?

Comment: FrobeniusSolve[] is indeed a nice shortcut. Thanks. Now that I think about it the header is somewhat misleading. The reason why I felt  I may have to declare an infinite array of integers is because I wanted to make the numbers 10 and 100 variables. Even then one can get by without having to declare an infinite array I guess. It is hard to guess that the problem I have described arises naturally while trying to compute the entropy of a physical system.

Comment: But I am unable to see how to Solve two Frobenius Equations Simultaneously..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the full problem, I don't know how to coax Mathematica into running 100 nested `Do`'s in a reasonable amount of time. Instead, I would use Mathematica to generate C-code that is then executed externally. In this way, the the full problem can be solved in about 40 seconds.

Here's the Mathematica code that generates the C-code. Assume that we want $\sum_{i=1}^{i_{\text{max}}}n_i=\text{sum}_0=10$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{i_{\text{max}}}in_i=\text{sum}_1=100$, and go to the full problem with $i_{\text{max}}=100$:

```
sum0 = 10;
sum1 = 100;
imax = 100;
f = OpenWrite["~/Desktop/loop.c"]; (* or whereever you want to save it *)
WriteString[f, "#include <stdio.h>\n"];
WriteString[f, "int main() {\n"];
WriteString[f, "int n[" <> ToString[imax] <> "];\n"];
WriteString[f, "int s0[" <> ToString[imax + 1] <> "];\n"];
WriteString[f, "int s1[" <> ToString[imax + 1] <> "];\n"];
WriteString[f, "s0[0]=s1[0]=0;\n"];
Do[WriteString[f, "for (n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]=0; (s0[" <> ToString[i - 1] <>
  "]+n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]<=" <> ToString[sum0] <> ") && (s1[" <> 
  ToString[i - 1] <> "]+" <> ToString[i] <> "*n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]<=" <> 
  ToString[sum1] <> "); n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]++) {\ns0[" <> ToString[i] <> 
  "]=s0[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]+n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "];\ns1[" <> 
  ToString[i] <> "]=s1[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]+" <> ToString[i] <> "*n[" <> 
  ToString[i - 1] <> "];\n"], {i, imax}];
WriteString[f, "if ((s0[" <> ToString[imax] <> "]==" <> ToString[sum0] <>
  ") && (s1[" <> ToString[imax] <> "]==" <> ToString[sum1] <> "))\n"];
WriteString[f, "printf(\""];
Do[WriteString[f, "%d "], {imax}];
WriteString[f, "\\n\", n[0]"];
Do[WriteString[f, ",n[" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "]"], {i, 2, imax}];
WriteString[f, ");\n"];
Do[WriteString[f, "}"], {imax + 1}];
WriteString[f, "\n"];
Close[f];
```

Compile this code in a terminal with

```bash
gcc -O3 loop.c -o loop
```

and run it with

```bash
./loop > loop.dat
```

On my laptop the code runs in about 40 seconds and generates 2'977'866 solutions. These solutions can be read into Mathematica with

```
data = ReadList["~/Desktop/loop.dat", Number, RecordLists -> True];
Dimensions[data]
```

> {2977866, 100}

To determine how many solutions you get as a function of $i_{\text{max}}$, first count how many nonzero $n_i$ are involved in each solution:

```
lengths = Replace[data, {x___, Except[0], 0 ...} :> Length[{x}] + 1, {1}];
```

Then count how many solutions have a length $\le i_{\text{max}}$ as a function of $i_{\text{max}}$:

```
Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[Lookup[Counts[lengths], Range[100], 0]]}]
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 0}, {8, 0}, {9, 0}, {10, 1}, {11, 42}, {12, 463}, {13, 2507}, {14, 8861}, {15, 23601}, {16, 51376}, {17, 96314}, {18, 161073}, {19, 246448}, {20, 351344}, {21, 473259}, {22, 608704}, {23, 753813}, {24, 904675}, {25, 1057740}, {26, 1209868}, {27, 1358546}, {28, 1501764}, {29, 1638097}, {30, 1766535}, {31, 1886522}, {32, 1997755}, {33, 2100247}, {34, 2194143}, {35, 2279771}, {36, 2357509}, {37, 2427846}, {38, 2491252}, {39, 2548263}, {40, 2599369}, {41, 2645085}, {42, 2685871}, {43, 2722199}, {44, 2754470}, {45, 2783097}, {46, 2808428}, {47, 2830808}, {48, 2850528}, {49, 2867882}, {50, 2883106}, {51, 2896444}, {52, 2908092}, {53, 2918248}, {54, 2927072}, {55, 2934729}, {56, 2941344}, {57, 2947052}, {58, 2951956}, {59, 2956162}, {60, 2959751}, {61, 2962811}, {62, 2965403}, {63, 2967597}, {64, 2969442}, {65, 2970991}, {66, 2972282}, {67, 2973358}, {68, 2974245}, {69, 2974977}, {70, 2975575}, {71, 2976063}, {72, 2976456}, {73, 2976774}, {74, 2977026}, {75, 2977227}, {76, 2977384}, {77, 2977507}, {78, 2977601}, {79, 2977674}, {80, 2977728}, {81, 2977769}, {82, 2977799}, {83, 2977821}, {84, 2977836}, {85, 2977847}, {86, 2977854}, {87, 2977859}, {88, 2977862}, {89, 2977864}, {90, 2977865}, {91, 2977866}, {92, 2977866}, {93, 2977866}, {94, 2977866}, {95, 2977866}, {96, 2977866}, {97, 2977866}, {98, 2977866}, {99, 2977866}, {100, 2977866}}

---

For reference, here's the generated C-code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n[100];
int s0[101];
int s1[101];
s0[0]=s1[0]=0;
for (n[0]=0; (s0[0]+n[0]<=10) && (s1[0]+1*n[0]<=100); n[0]++) {
s0[1]=s0[0]+n[0];
s1[1]=s1[0]+1*n[0];
for (n[1]=0; (s0[1]+n[1]<=10) && (s1[1]+2*n[1]<=100); n[1]++) {
s0[2]=s0[1]+n[1];
s1[2]=s1[1]+2*n[1];
for (n[2]=0; (s0[2]+n[2]<=10) && (s1[2]+3*n[2]<=100); n[2]++) {
s0[3]=s0[2]+n[2];
s1[3]=s1[2]+3*n[2];
for (n[3]=0; (s0[3]+n[3]<=10) && (s1[3]+4*n[3]<=100); n[3]++) {
s0[4]=s0[3]+n[3];
s1[4]=s1[3]+4*n[3];
for (n[4]=0; (s0[4]+n[4]<=10) && (s1[4]+5*n[4]<=100); n[4]++) {
s0[5]=s0[4]+n[4];
s1[5]=s1[4]+5*n[4];
for (n[5]=0; (s0[5]+n[5]<=10) && (s1[5]+6*n[5]<=100); n[5]++) {
s0[6]=s0[5]+n[5];
s1[6]=s1[5]+6*n[5];
for (n[6]=0; (s0[6]+n[6]<=10) && (s1[6]+7*n[6]<=100); n[6]++) {
s0[7]=s0[6]+n[6];
s1[7]=s1[6]+7*n[6];
for (n[7]=0; (s0[7]+n[7]<=10) && (s1[7]+8*n[7]<=100); n[7]++) {
s0[8]=s0[7]+n[7];
s1[8]=s1[7]+8*n[7];
for (n[8]=0; (s0[8]+n[8]<=10) && (s1[8]+9*n[8]<=100); n[8]++) {
s0[9]=s0[8]+n[8];
s1[9]=s1[8]+9*n[8];
for (n[9]=0; (s0[9]+n[9]<=10) && (s1[9]+10*n[9]<=100); n[9]++) {
s0[10]=s0[9]+n[9];
s1[10]=s1[9]+10*n[9];
for (n[10]=0; (s0[10]+n[10]<=10) && (s1[10]+11*n[10]<=100); n[10]++) {
s0[11]=s0[10]+n[10];
s1[11]=s1[10]+11*n[10];
for (n[11]=0; (s0[11]+n[11]<=10) && (s1[11]+12*n[11]<=100); n[11]++) {
s0[12]=s0[11]+n[11];
s1[12]=s1[11]+12*n[11];
for (n[12]=0; (s0[12]+n[12]<=10) && (s1[12]+13*n[12]<=100); n[12]++) {
s0[13]=s0[12]+n[12];
s1[13]=s1[12]+13*n[12];
for (n[13]=0; (s0[13]+n[13]<=10) && (s1[13]+14*n[13]<=100); n[13]++) {
s0[14]=s0[13]+n[13];
s1[14]=s1[13]+14*n[13];
for (n[14]=0; (s0[14]+n[14]<=10) && (s1[14]+15*n[14]<=100); n[14]++) {
s0[15]=s0[14]+n[14];
s1[15]=s1[14]+15*n[14];
for (n[15]=0; (s0[15]+n[15]<=10) && (s1[15]+16*n[15]<=100); n[15]++) {
s0[16]=s0[15]+n[15];
s1[16]=s1[15]+16*n[15];
for (n[16]=0; (s0[16]+n[16]<=10) && (s1[16]+17*n[16]<=100); n[16]++) {
s0[17]=s0[16]+n[16];
s1[17]=s1[16]+17*n[16];
for (n[17]=0; (s0[17]+n[17]<=10) && (s1[17]+18*n[17]<=100); n[17]++) {
s0[18]=s0[17]+n[17];
s1[18]=s1[17]+18*n[17];
for (n[18]=0; (s0[18]+n[18]<=10) && (s1[18]+19*n[18]<=100); n[18]++) {
s0[19]=s0[18]+n[18];
s1[19]=s1[18]+19*n[18];
for (n[19]=0; (s0[19]+n[19]<=10) && (s1[19]+20*n[19]<=100); n[19]++) {
s0[20]=s0[19]+n[19];
s1[20]=s1[19]+20*n[19];
for (n[20]=0; (s0[20]+n[20]<=10) && (s1[20]+21*n[20]<=100); n[20]++) {
s0[21]=s0[20]+n[20];
s1[21]=s1[20]+21*n[20];
for (n[21]=0; (s0[21]+n[21]<=10) && (s1[21]+22*n[21]<=100); n[21]++) {
s0[22]=s0[21]+n[21];
s1[22]=s1[21]+22*n[21];
for (n[22]=0; (s0[22]+n[22]<=10) && (s1[22]+23*n[22]<=100); n[22]++) {
s0[23]=s0[22]+n[22];
s1[23]=s1[22]+23*n[22];
for (n[23]=0; (s0[23]+n[23]<=10) && (s1[23]+24*n[23]<=100); n[23]++) {
s0[24]=s0[23]+n[23];
s1[24]=s1[23]+24*n[23];
for (n[24]=0; (s0[24]+n[24]<=10) && (s1[24]+25*n[24]<=100); n[24]++) {
s0[25]=s0[24]+n[24];
s1[25]=s1[24]+25*n[24];
for (n[25]=0; (s0[25]+n[25]<=10) && (s1[25]+26*n[25]<=100); n[25]++) {
s0[26]=s0[25]+n[25];
s1[26]=s1[25]+26*n[25];
for (n[26]=0; (s0[26]+n[26]<=10) && (s1[26]+27*n[26]<=100); n[26]++) {
s0[27]=s0[26]+n[26];
s1[27]=s1[26]+27*n[26];
for (n[27]=0; (s0[27]+n[27]<=10) && (s1[27]+28*n[27]<=100); n[27]++) {
s0[28]=s0[27]+n[27];
s1[28]=s1[27]+28*n[27];
for (n[28]=0; (s0[28]+n[28]<=10) && (s1[28]+29*n[28]<=100); n[28]++) {
s0[29]=s0[28]+n[28];
s1[29]=s1[28]+29*n[28];
for (n[29]=0; (s0[29]+n[29]<=10) && (s1[29]+30*n[29]<=100); n[29]++) {
s0[30]=s0[29]+n[29];
s1[30]=s1[29]+30*n[29];
for (n[30]=0; (s0[30]+n[30]<=10) && (s1[30]+31*n[30]<=100); n[30]++) {
s0[31]=s0[30]+n[30];
s1[31]=s1[30]+31*n[30];
for (n[31]=0; (s0[31]+n[31]<=10) && (s1[31]+32*n[31]<=100); n[31]++) {
s0[32]=s0[31]+n[31];
s1[32]=s1[31]+32*n[31];
for (n[32]=0; (s0[32]+n[32]<=10) && (s1[32]+33*n[32]<=100); n[32]++) {
s0[33]=s0[32]+n[32];
s1[33]=s1[32]+33*n[32];
for (n[33]=0; (s0[33]+n[33]<=10) && (s1[33]+34*n[33]<=100); n[33]++) {
s0[34]=s0[33]+n[33];
s1[34]=s1[33]+34*n[33];
for (n[34]=0; (s0[34]+n[34]<=10) && (s1[34]+35*n[34]<=100); n[34]++) {
s0[35]=s0[34]+n[34];
s1[35]=s1[34]+35*n[34];
for (n[35]=0; (s0[35]+n[35]<=10) && (s1[35]+36*n[35]<=100); n[35]++) {
s0[36]=s0[35]+n[35];
s1[36]=s1[35]+36*n[35];
for (n[36]=0; (s0[36]+n[36]<=10) && (s1[36]+37*n[36]<=100); n[36]++) {
s0[37]=s0[36]+n[36];
s1[37]=s1[36]+37*n[36];
for (n[37]=0; (s0[37]+n[37]<=10) && (s1[37]+38*n[37]<=100); n[37]++) {
s0[38]=s0[37]+n[37];
s1[38]=s1[37]+38*n[37];
for (n[38]=0; (s0[38]+n[38]<=10) && (s1[38]+39*n[38]<=100); n[38]++) {
s0[39]=s0[38]+n[38];
s1[39]=s1[38]+39*n[38];
for (n[39]=0; (s0[39]+n[39]<=10) && (s1[39]+40*n[39]<=100); n[39]++) {
s0[40]=s0[39]+n[39];
s1[40]=s1[39]+40*n[39];
for (n[40]=0; (s0[40]+n[40]<=10) && (s1[40]+41*n[40]<=100); n[40]++) {
s0[41]=s0[40]+n[40];
s1[41]=s1[40]+41*n[40];
for (n[41]=0; (s0[41]+n[41]<=10) && (s1[41]+42*n[41]<=100); n[41]++) {
s0[42]=s0[41]+n[41];
s1[42]=s1[41]+42*n[41];
for (n[42]=0; (s0[42]+n[42]<=10) && (s1[42]+43*n[42]<=100); n[42]++) {
s0[43]=s0[42]+n[42];
s1[43]=s1[42]+43*n[42];
for (n[43]=0; (s0[43]+n[43]<=10) && (s1[43]+44*n[43]<=100); n[43]++) {
s0[44]=s0[43]+n[43];
s1[44]=s1[43]+44*n[43];
for (n[44]=0; (s0[44]+n[44]<=10) && (s1[44]+45*n[44]<=100); n[44]++) {
s0[45]=s0[44]+n[44];
s1[45]=s1[44]+45*n[44];
for (n[45]=0; (s0[45]+n[45]<=10) && (s1[45]+46*n[45]<=100); n[45]++) {
s0[46]=s0[45]+n[45];
s1[46]=s1[45]+46*n[45];
for (n[46]=0; (s0[46]+n[46]<=10) && (s1[46]+47*n[46]<=100); n[46]++) {
s0[47]=s0[46]+n[46];
s1[47]=s1[46]+47*n[46];
for (n[47]=0; (s0[47]+n[47]<=10) && (s1[47]+48*n[47]<=100); n[47]++) {
s0[48]=s0[47]+n[47];
s1[48]=s1[47]+48*n[47];
for (n[48]=0; (s0[48]+n[48]<=10) && (s1[48]+49*n[48]<=100); n[48]++) {
s0[49]=s0[48]+n[48];
s1[49]=s1[48]+49*n[48];
for (n[49]=0; (s0[49]+n[49]<=10) && (s1[49]+50*n[49]<=100); n[49]++) {
s0[50]=s0[49]+n[49];
s1[50]=s1[49]+50*n[49];
for (n[50]=0; (s0[50]+n[50]<=10) && (s1[50]+51*n[50]<=100); n[50]++) {
s0[51]=s0[50]+n[50];
s1[51]=s1[50]+51*n[50];
for (n[51]=0; (s0[51]+n[51]<=10) && (s1[51]+52*n[51]<=100); n[51]++) {
s0[52]=s0[51]+n[51];
s1[52]=s1[51]+52*n[51];
for (n[52]=0; (s0[52]+n[52]<=10) && (s1[52]+53*n[52]<=100); n[52]++) {
s0[53]=s0[52]+n[52];
s1[53]=s1[52]+53*n[52];
for (n[53]=0; (s0[53]+n[53]<=10) && (s1[53]+54*n[53]<=100); n[53]++) {
s0[54]=s0[53]+n[53];
s1[54]=s1[53]+54*n[53];
for (n[54]=0; (s0[54]+n[54]<=10) && (s1[54]+55*n[54]<=100); n[54]++) {
s0[55]=s0[54]+n[54];
s1[55]=s1[54]+55*n[54];
for (n[55]=0; (s0[55]+n[55]<=10) && (s1[55]+56*n[55]<=100); n[55]++) {
s0[56]=s0[55]+n[55];
s1[56]=s1[55]+56*n[55];
for (n[56]=0; (s0[56]+n[56]<=10) && (s1[56]+57*n[56]<=100); n[56]++) {
s0[57]=s0[56]+n[56];
s1[57]=s1[56]+57*n[56];
for (n[57]=0; (s0[57]+n[57]<=10) && (s1[57]+58*n[57]<=100); n[57]++) {
s0[58]=s0[57]+n[57];
s1[58]=s1[57]+58*n[57];
for (n[58]=0; (s0[58]+n[58]<=10) && (s1[58]+59*n[58]<=100); n[58]++) {
s0[59]=s0[58]+n[58];
s1[59]=s1[58]+59*n[58];
for (n[59]=0; (s0[59]+n[59]<=10) && (s1[59]+60*n[59]<=100); n[59]++) {
s0[60]=s0[59]+n[59];
s1[60]=s1[59]+60*n[59];
for (n[60]=0; (s0[60]+n[60]<=10) && (s1[60]+61*n[60]<=100); n[60]++) {
s0[61]=s0[60]+n[60];
s1[61]=s1[60]+61*n[60];
for (n[61]=0; (s0[61]+n[61]<=10) && (s1[61]+62*n[61]<=100); n[61]++) {
s0[62]=s0[61]+n[61];
s1[62]=s1[61]+62*n[61];
for (n[62]=0; (s0[62]+n[62]<=10) && (s1[62]+63*n[62]<=100); n[62]++) {
s0[63]=s0[62]+n[62];
s1[63]=s1[62]+63*n[62];
for (n[63]=0; (s0[63]+n[63]<=10) && (s1[63]+64*n[63]<=100); n[63]++) {
s0[64]=s0[63]+n[63];
s1[64]=s1[63]+64*n[63];
for (n[64]=0; (s0[64]+n[64]<=10) && (s1[64]+65*n[64]<=100); n[64]++) {
s0[65]=s0[64]+n[64];
s1[65]=s1[64]+65*n[64];
for (n[65]=0; (s0[65]+n[65]<=10) && (s1[65]+66*n[65]<=100); n[65]++) {
s0[66]=s0[65]+n[65];
s1[66]=s1[65]+66*n[65];
for (n[66]=0; (s0[66]+n[66]<=10) && (s1[66]+67*n[66]<=100); n[66]++) {
s0[67]=s0[66]+n[66];
s1[67]=s1[66]+67*n[66];
for (n[67]=0; (s0[67]+n[67]<=10) && (s1[67]+68*n[67]<=100); n[67]++) {
s0[68]=s0[67]+n[67];
s1[68]=s1[67]+68*n[67];
for (n[68]=0; (s0[68]+n[68]<=10) && (s1[68]+69*n[68]<=100); n[68]++) {
s0[69]=s0[68]+n[68];
s1[69]=s1[68]+69*n[68];
for (n[69]=0; (s0[69]+n[69]<=10) && (s1[69]+70*n[69]<=100); n[69]++) {
s0[70]=s0[69]+n[69];
s1[70]=s1[69]+70*n[69];
for (n[70]=0; (s0[70]+n[70]<=10) && (s1[70]+71*n[70]<=100); n[70]++) {
s0[71]=s0[70]+n[70];
s1[71]=s1[70]+71*n[70];
for (n[71]=0; (s0[71]+n[71]<=10) && (s1[71]+72*n[71]<=100); n[71]++) {
s0[72]=s0[71]+n[71];
s1[72]=s1[71]+72*n[71];
for (n[72]=0; (s0[72]+n[72]<=10) && (s1[72]+73*n[72]<=100); n[72]++) {
s0[73]=s0[72]+n[72];
s1[73]=s1[72]+73*n[72];
for (n[73]=0; (s0[73]+n[73]<=10) && (s1[73]+74*n[73]<=100); n[73]++) {
s0[74]=s0[73]+n[73];
s1[74]=s1[73]+74*n[73];
for (n[74]=0; (s0[74]+n[74]<=10) && (s1[74]+75*n[74]<=100); n[74]++) {
s0[75]=s0[74]+n[74];
s1[75]=s1[74]+75*n[74];
for (n[75]=0; (s0[75]+n[75]<=10) && (s1[75]+76*n[75]<=100); n[75]++) {
s0[76]=s0[75]+n[75];
s1[76]=s1[75]+76*n[75];
for (n[76]=0; (s0[76]+n[76]<=10) && (s1[76]+77*n[76]<=100); n[76]++) {
s0[77]=s0[76]+n[76];
s1[77]=s1[76]+77*n[76];
for (n[77]=0; (s0[77]+n[77]<=10) && (s1[77]+78*n[77]<=100); n[77]++) {
s0[78]=s0[77]+n[77];
s1[78]=s1[77]+78*n[77];
for (n[78]=0; (s0[78]+n[78]<=10) && (s1[78]+79*n[78]<=100); n[78]++) {
s0[79]=s0[78]+n[78];
s1[79]=s1[78]+79*n[78];
for (n[79]=0; (s0[79]+n[79]<=10) && (s1[79]+80*n[79]<=100); n[79]++) {
s0[80]=s0[79]+n[79];
s1[80]=s1[79]+80*n[79];
for (n[80]=0; (s0[80]+n[80]<=10) && (s1[80]+81*n[80]<=100); n[80]++) {
s0[81]=s0[80]+n[80];
s1[81]=s1[80]+81*n[80];
for (n[81]=0; (s0[81]+n[81]<=10) && (s1[81]+82*n[81]<=100); n[81]++) {
s0[82]=s0[81]+n[81];
s1[82]=s1[81]+82*n[81];
for (n[82]=0; (s0[82]+n[82]<=10) && (s1[82]+83*n[82]<=100); n[82]++) {
s0[83]=s0[82]+n[82];
s1[83]=s1[82]+83*n[82];
for (n[83]=0; (s0[83]+n[83]<=10) && (s1[83]+84*n[83]<=100); n[83]++) {
s0[84]=s0[83]+n[83];
s1[84]=s1[83]+84*n[83];
for (n[84]=0; (s0[84]+n[84]<=10) && (s1[84]+85*n[84]<=100); n[84]++) {
s0[85]=s0[84]+n[84];
s1[85]=s1[84]+85*n[84];
for (n[85]=0; (s0[85]+n[85]<=10) && (s1[85]+86*n[85]<=100); n[85]++) {
s0[86]=s0[85]+n[85];
s1[86]=s1[85]+86*n[85];
for (n[86]=0; (s0[86]+n[86]<=10) && (s1[86]+87*n[86]<=100); n[86]++) {
s0[87]=s0[86]+n[86];
s1[87]=s1[86]+87*n[86];
for (n[87]=0; (s0[87]+n[87]<=10) && (s1[87]+88*n[87]<=100); n[87]++) {
s0[88]=s0[87]+n[87];
s1[88]=s1[87]+88*n[87];
for (n[88]=0; (s0[88]+n[88]<=10) && (s1[88]+89*n[88]<=100); n[88]++) {
s0[89]=s0[88]+n[88];
s1[89]=s1[88]+89*n[88];
for (n[89]=0; (s0[89]+n[89]<=10) && (s1[89]+90*n[89]<=100); n[89]++) {
s0[90]=s0[89]+n[89];
s1[90]=s1[89]+90*n[89];
for (n[90]=0; (s0[90]+n[90]<=10) && (s1[90]+91*n[90]<=100); n[90]++) {
s0[91]=s0[90]+n[90];
s1[91]=s1[90]+91*n[90];
for (n[91]=0; (s0[91]+n[91]<=10) && (s1[91]+92*n[91]<=100); n[91]++) {
s0[92]=s0[91]+n[91];
s1[92]=s1[91]+92*n[91];
for (n[92]=0; (s0[92]+n[92]<=10) && (s1[92]+93*n[92]<=100); n[92]++) {
s0[93]=s0[92]+n[92];
s1[93]=s1[92]+93*n[92];
for (n[93]=0; (s0[93]+n[93]<=10) && (s1[93]+94*n[93]<=100); n[93]++) {
s0[94]=s0[93]+n[93];
s1[94]=s1[93]+94*n[93];
for (n[94]=0; (s0[94]+n[94]<=10) && (s1[94]+95*n[94]<=100); n[94]++) {
s0[95]=s0[94]+n[94];
s1[95]=s1[94]+95*n[94];
for (n[95]=0; (s0[95]+n[95]<=10) && (s1[95]+96*n[95]<=100); n[95]++) {
s0[96]=s0[95]+n[95];
s1[96]=s1[95]+96*n[95];
for (n[96]=0; (s0[96]+n[96]<=10) && (s1[96]+97*n[96]<=100); n[96]++) {
s0[97]=s0[96]+n[96];
s1[97]=s1[96]+97*n[96];
for (n[97]=0; (s0[97]+n[97]<=10) && (s1[97]+98*n[97]<=100); n[97]++) {
s0[98]=s0[97]+n[97];
s1[98]=s1[97]+98*n[97];
for (n[98]=0; (s0[98]+n[98]<=10) && (s1[98]+99*n[98]<=100); n[98]++) {
s0[99]=s0[98]+n[98];
s1[99]=s1[98]+99*n[98];
for (n[99]=0; (s0[99]+n[99]<=10) && (s1[99]+100*n[99]<=100); n[99]++) {
s0[100]=s0[99]+n[99];
s1[100]=s1[99]+100*n[99];
if ((s0[100]==10) && (s1[100]==100))
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d \n", n[0],n[1],n[2],n[3],n[4],n[5],n[6],n[7],n[8],n[9],n[10],n[11],n[12],n[13],n[14],n[15],n[16],n[17],n[18],n[19],n[20],n[21],n[22],n[23],n[24],n[25],n[26],n[27],n[28],n[29],n[30],n[31],n[32],n[33],n[34],n[35],n[36],n[37],n[38],n[39],n[40],n[41],n[42],n[43],n[44],n[45],n[46],n[47],n[48],n[49],n[50],n[51],n[52],n[53],n[54],n[55],n[56],n[57],n[58],n[59],n[60],n[61],n[62],n[63],n[64],n[65],n[66],n[67],n[68],n[69],n[70],n[71],n[72],n[73],n[74],n[75],n[76],n[77],n[78],n[79],n[80],n[81],n[82],n[83],n[84],n[85],n[86],n[87],n[88],n[89],n[90],n[91],n[92],n[93],n[94],n[95],n[96],n[97],n[98],n[99]);
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Surely someone more skilled than me can find a C++ template programming way of generating the same code without needing Mathematica in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

All the $n_i$ with $i>100$ must be zero, so it's enough to look at $n_1\ldots n_{100}$. The below code will crash for this large system though.

However, if you only look at $i\le i_{\text{max}}$ (and you may make $i_{\text{max}}$ as large as your computer allows, though probably not 100 as truly needed), then you could first generate the list of all tuples of length `imax` that sum to 10:

```
imax = 15;
S = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[10, {imax}, Range[0, 10]];
```

Careful with memory, there are $\binom{i_{\text{max}} + 9}{10}$ of them. For $i_{\text{max}}=100$ this will generate 42'634'215'112'710 tuples of length 100.

Then find the positions of those that sum to 100 when dotted with the vector $\{1,2,3,\ldots,i_{\text{max}}\}$:

```
P = Position[S.Range[imax], 100] // Flatten
```

> {10, 39, 276, 359, 398, 573, ...}

Show the results:

```
S[[P]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0}, ...}

To calculate the number of solutions as a function of $i_{\text{max}}$:

```
num[imax_Integer /; 1 <= imax <= 100] := Module[{S},
  S = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[10, {imax}, Range[0, 10]];
  P = Position[S.Range[imax], 100] // Flatten;
  Length[P]]

Table[num[imax], {imax, 1, 20}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 42, 463, 2507, 8861, 23601, 51376, 96314, 161073, 246448, 351344}

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a code fragment that computes the number of such tuples as a function of imax

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to name your variables as elements of an array (instead of having separate names). For example, allA defines 100 variables called a[1], a[2], etc. You can use these in Solve directly, and force them all to be positive integers:

```
 n = 100;
 allA = Array[a, n]
 Solve[{Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 100 && Sum[i a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 1000 &&
        Thread[allA >= ConstantArray[0, n]] //.List -> And}, allA, Integers]
```

We can test that it works by using a simple case where n=3

```
n = 3;
allA = Array[a, n]
Solve[{Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 6 && Sum[i a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 14 && 
    Thread[allA >= ConstantArray[0, n]] //.List -> And}, allA, Integers]
```

which returns three answers:

```
{{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 4, a[3] -> 2}, {a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 3}
 {a[1] -> 2, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 4}}
```

For larger n, if you don't want to wait for all the answers, you can replace Solve with FindInstance and just get a few answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used FrobeniusSolve but in the most wasteful way imaginable. I solved these two equations separately and found the intersection of the solutions and counted how many there are as a function of U. The Log of this number is the entropy of the system. The physical model is a set of N identical marbles occupying an infinite staircase where ascending each step implies gaining a unit of energy. The total energy of the system is U.

```
n1 + n2 + ... + nK = N
n1 + 2 n2 + .... + K nK = U
```

It is easy to see that

```
K = U - N + 1
```

The Code I wrote is,

```
funit[x_] := 1
Arr[max_] := Array[funit, max]

FSolveTotN[ N_, U_] 
:= FrobeniusSolve[ Arr[U - N + 1], N]

FSolveEgy[N_, U_] 
:= FrobeniusSolve[ Range[U - N + 1], U]

MarbleList[N_, U_] 
:= Intersection[FSolveTotN[N, U],FSolveEgy[N, U]]
```

Entropy of N marbles on an infinite staircase as a function of the total energy U

```
S[N_, U_] := Log[ Length[MarbleList[N, U]] ]
TASK[N_] := Table[{U, S[N, U]},{U, N+1, N+15}]

ListPlot[TASK[3], AxesLabel -> {"U", "Entropy"}]

TASK[3] is

{{4, 0}, {5, Log[2]}, {6, Log[3]}, {7, Log[4]}, 
{8, Log[5]}, {9,Log[7]}, {10, Log[8]}, 
{11, Log[10]}, {12, Log[12]}, {13,Log[14]},
{14, Log[16]}, {15, Log[19]}, {16, Log[21]},
{17, Log[24]}, {18, Log[27]}}
```