# All possible A of Ax=b with constraints on A

Tags: probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra

I have a linear problem that I want to solve but the method is quite different from normal, the problem is still Ax=b. However,
in this instant I have A being unknown, apart from the fact that each entry in A can only be zero or 1. Further I have x being known and fixed, the same holds for b.

My question, is it a easy method for getting mathematica to spit out all possible A such that Ax=b given conditions on A.

I tried doing a number of for loops etc, however, I have completely given up after number of hours and the expectation that my effort is incorrect.

Comment: You should be able to use `Tuples[]` + `Partition[]` (after perhaps filtering out nonsingular candidates).

Comment: Please post a concrete example. Also note this is essentially the same as [this recent MSE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192308/frobeniussolve-with-solutions-only-being-0-or-1-being-acceptable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to code up your problem with `Solve` automatically:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
b = Reverse[x];
sol[x_List, b_List] /; Length[x] === Length[b] := Module[{mat, vars},
   mat = Array[\[FormalM], Length[x]*{1, 1}]; (* construct a matrix of variables*)
   vars = Flatten[mat];
   mat /. 
    Solve[And @@ Thread[mat.x == b] (* Construct the equations *) 
      && vars ∈ Integers && And @@ Thread[0 <= vars <= 1] (* constraints *),
     vars
    ]
   ];
matrixSolutions = sol[x, b]
```

> {{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}

As you can see, 2 solutions were found. Check that the residuals of the solutions are zero vectors:

```
#.x - b & /@ matrixSolutions
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

It works, but I don't know how scalable this approach is. Instead of `Solve`, you can also use `NSolve` and/or `FindInstance` (you can just replace `Solve` with any of those two functions in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same questions as

[FrobeniusSolve with solutions only being 0 or 1 being acceptable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192308/frobeniussolve-with-solutions-only-being-0-or-1-being-acceptable)

Using @Sjoerd's problem

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
b = Reverse[x];
```

Can write solution as

```
res = Tuples@(Select[FrobeniusSolve[x, #], Max@# <= 1 &] & /@ b)

(* {{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
   {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}  *)
```